# Run Play application in production mode using dist taks

Tags: deployment, playframework

I am using 'dist' task to generate a distribution of my play application. But if I unzip the generated artifact, in the bin/ directory I have access to the bash file generated by the 'dist' task. The last line of the script is : run "$@"

I saw in the official Play Framework documentation that 'run' command should not be used in production mode, and the recommended way is to generated a distribution with task 'dist'

Why 'dist' is generating a bash script which is using 'run' commmand if it is not recommended in production mode?

I am asking this, because when I deploy my application in production, the first request is slow...it seems the development behavior. But I am using the 'dist' command.

I would appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the files and commands you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing two different things.

The `run` command stated in the Play documentation is a SBT command, that will start your app in dev mode. So to use that command you have to use activator or sbt (ex: `./activator run`).

The `run` you see in that script is a bash function (defined a little above), that will start your app in production mode. A little snippet from that function:

```
# Actually runs the script.
run() {
  # TODO - check for sane environment
  # process the combined args, then reset "$@" to the residuals
  # (...)
  execRunner "$java_cmd" \
    ${java_opts[@]} \
    "${java_args[@]}" \
    -cp "$(fix_classpath "$app_classpath")" \
    "${mainclass[@]}" \
    "${app_commands[@]}" \
    "${residual_args[@]}"

  (...)
}
```

So, if you use this script to run your app, it will start in production mode.

Comment: Oh! You are right. I am sorry for the mistake. Thank you for your answer.